# Discord.JS Bot hosting through Heroku throwing a 500 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, discord.js

I'm attempting to host my first attempt at a discord bot through Heroku, and despite linking my github repo & setting up the files necessary to accommodate the hosting (such as the Procfile), I am still getting the following error whilst attempting to deploy. (Note, builds are still successful.)

```
2021-09-29T15:50:35.129091+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at async WebSocketManager.connect (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:128:9)
2021-09-29T15:50:35.129091+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at async Client.login (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:245:7) {
2021-09-29T15:50:35.129091+00:00 app[Worker.1]:   code: 500,
2021-09-29T15:50:35.129093+00:00 app[Worker.1]:   method: 'get',
2021-09-29T15:50:35.129093+00:00 app[Worker.1]:   path: '/gateway/bot',
2021-09-29T15:50:35.129093+00:00 app[Worker.1]:   requestData: { json: undefined, files: [] }
2021-09-29T15:50:35.129093+00:00 app[Worker.1]: }
2021-09-29T15:50:35.248528+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-09-29T15:50:35.410802+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

I think it may have something to do with the location of the Procfile, but honestly have no idea. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Heroku problem, but Discord API error, which means: Internal Server Error. What can be caused by discord having any problems on their side, so I suggest you to wait a little and try again!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).